# Distinct query not very distinct

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following query...

```
Select
distinct r.LocSeq
,r.ChargeSeq
,r.Heat
,ISNULL(r.status,'') as status
,r.Grade
,r.FinalProd
,s.Location
,s.RollRecID
,s.ShiftIdent
,s.prodtime
,ts.Super
,ts.Oper
FROM (NYS1SawPieces s inner join NYS1Reheat r on r.LocSeq = s.rollrecid) 
join NYS1FinishShiftInfo ts on s.ShiftIdent = ts.ShiftID 
where s.ShiftIdent = '05/21/15154C' and s.Location = 'PILERS'
order by r.LocSeq , s.RollRecID
```

The trouble I need help with is that the s.prodtime is a date time element to a thousandth of a second, which keeps me from getting distinct returns. 
How do I need to re-arrange this to get the distinct returns and still have access to the time/date stamp?

Thanks guys for a great site and some very good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round the datetime to the nearest second:

```
select distinct
--
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, prodtime, 120) AS DATETIME) as prodtime,
--
-- rest of query the same
```

If rounding to the news rest second is still too fine grained, you can similarly round to other amounts by changing the format parameter (see documentation).

Answer (score 0):

If all other columns are equal, and you only get 1 row for a set, you can surround the offending column with an aggregation function and receive a single value.

For Example:

```
Select
distinct r.LocSeq
,r.ChargeSeq
,r.Heat
,ISNULL(r.status,'') as status
,r.Grade
,r.FinalProd
,s.Location
,s.RollRecID
,s.ShiftIdent
,MIN(s.prodtime)
,ts.Super
,ts.Oper
FROM (NYS1SawPieces s inner join NYS1Reheat r on r.LocSeq = s.rollrecid) 
join NYS1FinishShiftInfo ts on s.ShiftIdent = ts.ShiftID 
where s.ShiftIdent = '05/21/15154C' and s.Location = 'PILERS'
order by r.LocSeq , s.RollRecID
```

Take note that this is not a good behaviour, but should solve your problem.

Comment: This won't work, I have 100 rows returned and the 2 that HAVE to be distinct are the first 2 (LocSeq, and ChargeSeq), all the other may or may not be the same. If I takr the time/date element out, I get a perfect list of what I want. But I need access to the time of certain rowsets.

Comment: Can you provide an example of 4 rows, 2 of which should be in the result, and 2 that shouldn't (and please explain why)?